# Which to be used; "I only" or "I myself"? Or something else?

Tags: grammar

What should I say when I want to convey that the job was done by me when asked by someone?
(In the context of *no one but me*)

***I only did this*** or ***I myself did this***?

Comment: Definitely not the ***only*** version - that would invariably be interpreted as *I **merely** did it* (implying that I didn't do anything else, and/or that what I did was of little significance). Idiomatically, I think the most likely form would be *I did this **on my own*** (without assistance). The *I myself did this* would only be "natural" in contexts where it was to some extent "surprising" that you personally should have been the one who did it (*rather than someone else doing it*, not *with no assistance*).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the context.

If replying to a simple question

> Who did this?
>
> I did it.

If you are wanting to emphasize that it was you and not someone else:

> Did you pay someone to write your thesis?
>
> No, sir, I did it *myself*.

If you want to emphasize that you are the only one:

> Did John help with the yard work?
>
> No, he played games all day and I did it *by myself*.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. *I did it alone.*

This has the most precise meaning "no one but me". It may, depending on context, imply additional meanings, such as those given below, but it often simply communicates the fact "no one but me".

> 2. *I did it by myself.*

This phrase has the same meaning, but we more likely use it to emphasize that it's remarkable, interesting, or surprising that we did not have help (for example, because it was a lot of work or required a lot of time).

*I built the house by myself* (without any help).

*All by myself* intensifies this sense, and is commonly used when a child first does something independently.

> 3. *I did [or other past tense event verb] it myself.*

Also means "no one but me," but here the meaning often includes: ("and it is remarkable that I did it instead of having someone else do it for me", because, for example, it requires extraordinary skill).

*I made it myself* (of a pie, or cake, for example, instead of buying it from a bakery).

Answer (score 0):

I only did this.

I myself did this.

(The OP wants to convey the message that the job was done by him, not by anyone else).

I think neither of the sentences conveys the required message.  The first sentence  conveys the sense that I did this and not anyting else. In the second sentence, the reflexive pronoun "myself" has been used for emphasizing that I am referring to myself and not anybody else. In other words, it may mean that I personally did this.

I think even the sentence "I did this myself/by myself/on my own" doesn't convey the 0P's message because it means that I did this without anybody's help.

However, if we say "I am/was the only one who did this", it conveys the required sense.

Alternatively, you can say "I alone did this". According to Oxford Learner's Dictionary, "alone" can be used after a noun or pronoun to show that the person or thing mentioned is "the only one".

Comment: *Only I did this* can convey: *Only I have ever done it.*

Comment: @Jim Reynolds, your comments come across. I have edited my answer.

Comment: We still have the same problem however. *I am the only one who did this* more often means *No one else has done this before.* *I am the only one who (has) climbed K2.* :)

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/alone

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/only